# Vue-cli Interpreta secciones como rutas

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Acabo de instalar vuecli, y tengo un template que en el menu llama a un area del html a través de su id, por ejemplo:

Este enlace

```
<li class>
    <a href="#services">Services</a>
</li>
```

Debería llevar a la sección

```
<section class="services py-5" id="services">
    <div class="container py-md-5 py-3">
      <h5 class="heading mb-2">Exclusive Services</h5>
      <h3 class="heading mb-5">We Provide Awesome Services</h3>
      <div class="feature-grids row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-5">
          <div class="bottom-gd">
            <span>01</span>
            <h3 class="mt-4">Content Marketing</h3>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Integer sit amet mattis quam, sit amet ul tricies velit. Praesent
              ullam corper dui turpis dolor sit amet.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-5">
          <div class="bottom-gd">
            <span>02</span>
            <h3 class="mt-4">Distribution Content</h3>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Integer sit amet mattis quam, sit amet ul tricies velit. Praesent
              ullam corper dui turpis dolor sit amet.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-5">
          <div class="bottom-gd">
            <span>03</span>
            <h3 class="mt-4">Measurement Content</h3>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Integer sit amet mattis quam, sit amet ul tricies velit. Praesent
              ullam corper dui turpis dolor sit amet.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-5">
          <div class="bottom-gd">
            <span>04</span>
            <h3 class="mt-4">Editorial Content</h3>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Integer sit amet mattis quam, sit amet ul tricies velit. Praesent
              ullam corper dui turpis dolor sit amet.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-5">
          <div class="bottom-gd">
            <span>05</span>
            <h3 class="mt-4">Creative Content</h3>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Integer sit amet mattis quam, sit amet ul tricies velit. Praesent
              ullam corper dui turpis dolor sit amet.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-5">
          <div class="bottom-gd">
            <span>06</span>
            <h3 class="mt-4">Analytics Content</h3>
            <p class="mt-2">
              Integer sit amet mattis quam, sit amet ul tricies velit. Praesent
              ullam corper dui turpis dolor sit amet.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Pero en vez de ello me lleva a la ruta /services que ni siquiera existe.

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";


const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/About.vue"),
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Existe alguna manera que mis secciones las detecte como secciones y no intente llamar una ruta.

Comment: Descubrí que el error me lo está generando el `#` de vue para las rutas, pude repararlo en vue 2, pero en vue 3 viene esta nueva opción `history: createWebHashHistory(),`, si alguien sabe cual es la   función que elimina el hash con ello estoy seguro que resuelvo el problema.